# конфликт линковки при наличии одинаковых функций в разных единицах трансляции

Tags: c++

Test1.cpp

```
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Hello 1" << std::endl;
}
```

Test2.cpp

```
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Hello 2" << std::endl;
}
```

Итак в двух .срр файлах существуют функции с одинаковыми именами, которые используются только в этих файлах test1.cpp и test2.cpp соотвт.
При линковке получаем ошибку

```
fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Сделать данные функции членами классов или обернуть в неймспейсы не получается в виду древности и бородатости проекта: изменение сигнатуры влечет за собой множество правок.
Пока рассматрвиается вариант с неймспейсами

```
namespace n1
{

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Hello 1" << std::endl;
}

}
```

+добавление using namespace

Есть ли какие-то способы, позволяющие создать в разных единицах трасляции функции с одинаковыми именами, которые будут доступны только в этих единицах?

Comment: сделать функцию статической как в обычном С? Но я бы посоветовал просто переименовать в 1 файле (надо же только в 1 менять).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно объявить их как `static` или поместить в анонимное пространство имен.

Comment: я забыл про анонимные неймспейсы, их еще не планируют депрекейтнуть?

Comment: @goldstar_labs Нет, даже наоборот, планировали депрекейтить static

Comment: @VTT, планировали убрать `static` для определения функций?

Comment: @MrBin: Планировали запретить использование `static` для целей придания внутреннего связывания - эта роль переходит к анонимным пространствам имен. То есть `static` останется только для объявления статических членов классов и для объявления локальных статических переменных.